# To disable date picker in primefaces calendar

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is there any way where date picker can be disabled in **p:calendar** element and allow only manual entry of dates in mm/dd/yyyy format?

Comment: Like stg says, you don't want a date picker then; just give a validator-restricted input text field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a regular `inputText` element then?

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.dateValue}">  
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>  
</h:inputText>
```

By the way: The correct pattern letter for month is `M` not `m`, the letter `m` stands for minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p:calendar showOn="button" />
```

It leaves you the ability to type the date without getting the popup.

Comment: The `showOn` attribute is the client side event that displays the date picker, by setting it to `button` the user could still click the button and bring up the date picker. alpha123 only wants manual entry

Answer (score 1):

No popup and no button:

```
<p:calendar showOn="" />
```